# Save data and fill the elements to return to a page in Universal App Windows

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a question for navigation between pages in Universal Apps (Windows and Windows Phone 8.1). I have a page with various elements (Slider, ComboBox, etc ...), when I go to the next page and come back, the values return to the initial state, and not with the changes I had made. Can anyone tell me if it is possible to do with the values remain in the elements to return to the page? If possible, someone could show me how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by changing the value of `NavigationCacheMode` property to `Required` or `Enabled` in page constructor. You'll need to do this on a page by page basis.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
}
```

The difference is for `Enabled` it'll cache your pages up to the cache size, controlled by `Frame`'s `CacheSize` property. For `Required` it'll cache pages regardless of cache size.

Comment: Thank you very much friend. It is possible I do this in general as well as I did with HardwareBackButton_Pressed in App.xaml.cs?

Comment: @vtncgustavo Unfortunately you need to do this at page level.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is per page, in the xaml, like so

```
<Page
    x:Class="Universal.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Universal"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    NavigationCacheMode="Required">
```

An other way that would make your code reusable is to create a base class :

```
public class CachedPage : Page
{
    public CachedPage() : base()
    {
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.